# C# make file readonly

Tags: c#, readonly

I created an Outlook add-in that checks if some forbiden words are present in an email before it is sent. It simply compares a string containing the email with words present in a .CSV file.

I don't mind people being able to read that .CSV file, but I do not want them to be able to modify it, except if they are doing it using the Outlook add-in.

To do this, I wanted to change the properties of the file depending on the user. When using the addin, the admin user would get the Read/Write rights, whereas the otherones would only be able to read it. However, **outside** of the add-in, I want that file to be readonly for everyone.

I tried using `File.SetAttributes("myPath", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);` but then the user can simply go in the file properties, uncheck the "Readonly" option, and he can do whatever he wants ... Can I avoid this ? Is there a smarter option than the Readonly mod ?

Comment: Imo this isn't really a programming question: This is about using the Security properties of Windows to lock specific access rights to a file to specific users.  If a local user has administrative rights then there is very little you can do to prevent them from modifying a file.

Comment: Programs don't have permissions, users do. That's a basic of the windows security model.

Comment: @Martin I thought I could for example remove the "Readonly" option from the properties graphically displayed in the option, just to make it less obvious. Anyway, sorry I did not realise my question was off-topic, thank your quick reply though ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the stored file.
To perform any operations, application can decrypt it in memory. User will not be able to modify unless using the application. Forced user modification will corrupt the file and make it unusable.

Comment: yes but OP wants the file to be readable and in readonly mode only if any user is accessing the file without his application

Comment: Agree, but if the end goal is to discourage user to modify it out of the application, this could help.

Comment: i agree with your solution by encrypt the file to be not readable, by  this way only your application should be able to read the content of your file .

Comment: I thought about encryption, but the user can still modify the file and mess everything up. Thank you for you input though ! :)

Comment: if this is the route you want to take, you have got plenty of options:
1. you can conceal the file with some non-descriptive filename.
2. Replace the corrupt file, with a hard-coded file with basic words.

Comment: The first solution cannot work, because the first time the user uses the add-in, he needs to specify which file contains the list of forbidden words. I also thought of the second, but because different people can edit the file, it will change constantly. I could add a loop inside of the code that stores a copy on this file locally everytime you send a mail, if you are an admin. If the file is corrupted, the admin can replace it.

Comment: Actually, no. The list of admin will be stored in an encrypted file. I could just add on top of this file the path toward the forbiden words list, so no one knows where it is, but the admin. That is the best I'll get I think. If i keep the previous solution of saving a local copy, I can tick both of your options! Thank you very much for the discussion, helped a lot !! :)